# Multiple possibilities for a single variable (if statements) in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program that will ask the user to input a color and depending on the color they pick, python converts it to a number and prints that number.

Here's my code:

```
def main():
brown1 = 5
red1 = 6
orange1 = 3 
color1 = input("Color on resistor? (separated by comma) : ")
if color1 == "Brown" or "brown":
    color1 = brown1
    if color1 == "Red" or "red":
        color1 = red1   
        if color1 == "Orange" or "orange":
            color1 = orange1
print(color1)
main()
```

The problem is that Python only returns the last color, that is, 3. 
I'm just starting to program and I don't really know what else to do to this code for it to work. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Instead of using `if` everytime, use `elif`, that way only one of your assignement statements will be triggered.  Also, the indentation of those if/elif statements should be equal

Answer (score 4):

You problem is that the `if` statements are nested, when they should not. An inner `if` is only reached when the outer condition is true

You can also use a dict:

```
colors = {'brown': brown1, 'red': red1, 'orange': orange1}
color1 = colors[color1.lower()]
```

Comment: Definitely use a dict, and the lower method for something like this.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is that you have put `if` inside other `if`. So if the first condition satisfies then only the second condition is checked and so on. And also you have used `color1 == "Brown" or "brown"`, this will always return `True` because boolean of a non-empty string is `True`. You should do something like this:

```
def main():
    brown1 = 5
    red1 = 6
    orange1 = 3 
    color1 = input("Color on resistor? (separated by comma) : ")
    if color1 == "Brown" or color1 == "brown":
        color1 = brown1
    elif color1 == "Red" or color1 == "red":
        color1 = red1   
    elif color1 == "Orange" or color1 == "orange":
        color1 = orange1
    print(color1)
main()
```

A better solution would be to use dictionary.

```
color_dict = {'brown':5, 'red':6 ,'orange':3}
color1 = input("Color on resistor? (separated by comma) : ")
print color_dict[color1.lower()]
```

Comment: This works except for the _dict part.

Comment: @user2774311: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that the `if` statements should be like this:

```
if color1 == "Brown" or color1 == "brown":
    ...
```

This is because "brown" is a non-empty string, so it returns `True`, which means your `if` condition will always be true. So, it keeps entering the if statements till it reaches the last one.

Here's how we'd correct this particular mistake:

```
1. brown1 = 5
2. red1 = 6
3. orange1 = 3 
4. color1 = input("Color on resistor? (separated by comma) : ")
5. if color1 == "Brown" or color1 == "brown":
6.     color1 = brown1
7.     if color1 == "Red" or color1 == "red":
8.         color1 = red1   
9.         if color1 == "Orange" or color1 == "orange":
10.             color1 = orange1
11. print(color1)
```

Let's try to dry-run this program (manually go line-by-line to see what's happening). if `color1 = "brown"` then we'll enter the `if` statement at line `5`. Then we'll go to line `6`. This means `color1` is defined to be 5 now. Thus, `color1` can never be "Red" or "red". Additionally, if `color1` is not "brown" or "Brown", then it'll go to the next line with the same indentation, or `11`, which means it'll never check for red and orange.

What you want to accomplish can be done like this:

```
if color1 == "brown" or color1 == "Brown":
    color = 5
if color1 == "brown" or color1 == "Brown":
    color1 = 6
if color1 == "brown" or color1 == "Brown":
    color1 = 3
```

Now, a problem with this is that if we change the value of color1 in the lines 2 or 4, the remaining conditions may be true even though you don't want to check them again (For example: `if color==1: color=2; if color==2: color=1` resets color to 1 because the second condition is true once more). This is why `elif` or `else if` is recommended, making our new program:

```
if color1 == "brown" or color1 == "Brown":
    color = 5
elif color1 == "brown" or color1 == "Brown":
    color1 = 6
elif color1 == "brown" or color1 == "Brown":
    color1 = 3
```

Comment: The indented `if` statements are still a problem, if you input 'orange' you will never even make it to the assignment statement on line **10**, because you would've had to pass the checks on lines **5** and **7**, meaning that the color would have to be brown, red, and orange.

Comment: I like the idea of dry-running the program. I hadn't thought of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a check that `color1` belongs to `colors` to Lev Levitsky's solution.
To avoid ugly `KeyError` exceptions.

```
def main():
  color = {"brown": 5, "red": 6, "orange": 3}
  c = input("Color on resistor? (separated by comma) : ")
  c = c.lower()
  if c in color:
    print(color[c])
  else:
    print("Color not found")
```

Optionally the same can be written in a pythonic way

```
def main():
  color = {"brown": 5, "red": 6, "orange": 3}
  c = input("Color on resistor? (separated by comma) : ")
  c = c.lower()
  try:
    print(color[c])
  except KeyError:
    print("Color not found")
```

Comment: you can also use `color.get(c, None)` or some other sensible default value.

Comment: This made it work! Two questions: what difference is there between braces and parentheses? and what does the .lower() do?

Comment: @user2774311
`string.lower(s)`
Return a copy of s, but with upper case letters converted to lower case.

a trick to handle 'Brown', 'brown', 'BrOwN' etc. with one check